# Double query request with bad performances

Tags: sql, postgresql

For a custom paginate solution, I have to simple request:

```
SELECT id, column1, column2, column3
FROM my_table
WHERE column1 IS NOT NULL AND...
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

this one return the data of the page.

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM my_table WHERE column1 IS NOT NULL AND...
```

this one return the total of the table.

There is no problems on the first request, the perf are good.
But the second is soo slow... Of course id is an index (primary key)

Is there a way to return the result of the count request faster ? Or concatenate the 2 request in a single one ?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

You need to elaborate on the `where` clause.

One option is to add an index based on the `where` clause.  For this version:

```
SELECT COUNT(id)
FROM my_table
WHERE column1 IS NOT NULL ;
```

Change the `select` to either `COUNT(*)` or `COUNT(1)` -- I just find it cleaner to not reference a column if you are not really using it.

Then, you would use an index on `my_table(column1)`.

Another option is to create a filtered index:

```
create index filind_my_table on (id)
    where column1 is not null . . .;
```

Postgres should be able to use this index for your query, and it should run faster.

Comment: count(1) uses index? primary will be column 0, not one right?

Comment: Hi Gordon, indeed use count(*) instead of count(id) is a little bit faster, but it steel slow. For each of my columns, I create a simple index: CREATE INDEX column1_index ON my_table (column1 NULLS LAST); Should I create as much as index I have filtered ? (an index for is not null, another for is TRUE...) ?

Answer (score 0):

did you check your query result with execution plan?
it will show you if you have missing indexes in your query.

Comment: in SQL management, go to -> query -> select include execution plan and run your query. the missing indexes will be shown in your result panel.